# Are shimano 6700 and 6703 chainrings compatible?

Tags: shimano, chainring, compatibility, groupsets

I want to replace the chainrings of a group set Shimano Ultegra FC-6703. Unfortunately, I can't find the external chainring anymore. Can I use an external chainring FC-6700 (two-speeds) to replace an external chainring FC-6703 three speeds? According to [bikeimport.ch](https://bikeimport.ch/shop/product/3753/238) the bolt distances are the same.

Answer (score 6):

The FC-6703-specific 52-tooth outer chainring is Shimano model number WP-Y1LK98030.

The FC-6700-specific 52-tooth outer chainring is Shimano model number WP-Y1LJ98150.

Yes, the FC-6700 outer chainring will bolt up and would likely work. However, the difference in the model number indicates a difference in the part, likely the positioning of the shifting ramps (I have seen a similar difference in a Shimano big ring before where logic would seem that it should not be, but Shimano does what it does for a reason). If indeed the ramping is different, the shifting could be affected negatively, but I stress the "could."

As for availability, I have found two locations with the 52-tooth FC-6703 ring. It is not inexpensive as it is over $100 USD in both locations.

[FC-6703 52-tooth ring via Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005CMX8OG)

[FC-6703 52-tooth ring via Universal Cycles](https://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=36477)

The chainring you seek on the UC link is at the bottom of the page.

Both links are based in the US, not Europe.

Comment: I too have high praises for Universal Cycles. Beware the Stack Exchange rules discourage what appear to be product or business endorsements.

Comment: @Jeff - good point.  I will remove the endorsement for Universal Cycles from the answer. It’s a challenge to not endorse a resource that has been dependable to me in order to help others, but understand the boundaries, and applying them consistently.

Comment: Aside - Shimano has some particular rules about resellers selling their stuff to another market.   I used to be able to buy from Wiggle (UK) to NZ and even including shipping it was 1/3 cheaper.  Now I can only buy locally.